# Share IPv6 with other PCs at the network

Tags: windows, dhcp, ipv6

Since my new ISP does not yet provide native IPv6, I used a VPN-based tunnel to get  an /80. This works well, but I'm not sure how to give other PCs/phones/etc in the network their own IPv6 from that subnetwork.

Should I install a DHCP v6 server?

Windows 10.

Comment: Is it possible for you to get a /64 instead?

Comment: Perhaps on the next ISP upgrade, but at the moment, no.